# How can i check firstname already in the database and give a error message?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

here I am trying to submit a form.what i want to know is when user enters his firstname if that firstname is already in the database how can i prevent him from from submitting the form and give a error message.It should check first name when he is typing.

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$reqnum = $_POST['reqnum'];
$Mnumber = $_POST['Mnumber'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$sitename = $_POST['sitename'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];

    //if()
    //{
    $new_fname= $_POST['fname'];
    $xxx = mysql_query("SELECT fname FROM gotest WHERE fname = '$new_fname'")or die(mysql_error());
    $yyy = mysql_fetch_row($xxx);

    if(mysql_num_rows($xxx) > 0)
    {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gotest(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename,reqnum,payment) VALUES('$Mnumber','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename','$reqnum','$payment')");

        $r = mysql_insert_id();
        header("Location: http://uuuu.yyyyy.net/test/freecreate.php?rid=$r");

    }
    else
    {
        echo"error";
    }

}
```

Here is my form

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>gooooooooo </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/demo.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/codemirror.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="script.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function copyText() {
            src = document.getElementById("fname");
            dest = document.getElementById("sitename");
            dest.value = src.value;
        }


    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <img src="images/logo.png" width="200" align="center" id="logo" style="text-align: center" />
    </header>

    <div id="login-form" style="margin-top: 5px !important;">
        <form action="" method="post">

            <table align="middle"  border="0" style="margin: 0 auto; background: rgba(57, 134, 79, 0.64);" >
                <h1 align="middle" style="color: #fff">Create Your Web Site</h1></br></br>


                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="Mnumber" name="Mnumber" value=""  placeholder="Your Mobile Number" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="email" id="email" name="email"  value=""  placeholder="Your Email" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"   value=""   placeholder="Your First Name" onkeyup="copyText()"  required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="address" name="address" value=""  placeholder="Your Address" required /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="sitename" name="sitename" value=""  placeholder="Your Site name" readonly/></td>
                </tr>



                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit" id="btn-signup" name="btn-signup" style="background: #39864f; border: 1px solid #fff; cursor: hand">Create website</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
        <script>


</script>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p  style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" style="color: #fff">Powered By <img src="images/elogo.png" align="center" id="logo" style="text-align: center; height: 40px; width: 153px;padding-bottom: 10px;" /></a></p>
    </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: make http AJAX request on blur on that field.

Comment: @mitkosoft i am not familiar with the AJAX can u help me

Comment: first learn about ajax and then any issue ask here we will here all time @colombo

Comment: http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/  .... @colombo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to alter the condition because mysql_num_rows() returns number of rows fetched from database with your query.
Your query is for selecting number of rows which contains new_fname. This will return 1 if record available with that name.

So you need to check mysql_num_rows($xxx)>0, then echo error else do your work.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($xxx) > 0)
{
   echo"error"; 
}
else
{
   $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO gotest(Mnumber,email,fname,address,sitename,reqnum,payment) VALUES('$Mnumber','$email','$fname','$address','$sitename','$reqnum','$payment')");

    $r = mysql_insert_id();
    header("Location: http://uuuu.yyyyy.net/test/freecreate.php?rid=$r");
 }
```

### Using AJAX - Prevent user to submit form.

You can check by ajax as following

You need to attach jquery library to use jquery functions

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn-signup").attr('disabled', true); // This will disable submit button.
  $("#fname").keyup(function(){
     var fname = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
          url: "check_name.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {fname : fname }
          success: function(response){
              if(response=="ok")
              {
                 $("#btn-signup").attr('disabled', false); // Enable submit button.
              }
              else
              {
                alert("Fname is already exist.");
                $("#btn-signup").attr('disabled', true);
              }
          }
     });

  })
})
</script>
```

Your php script to check name already exist or not

check_name.php

```
<?php
    $new_fname= $_POST['fname'];
    $xxx = mysql_query("SELECT fname FROM gotest WHERE fname = '$new_fname'")or die(mysql_error());
    $yyy = mysql_fetch_row($xxx);

    if(mysql_num_rows($xxx) > 0)
    {
       echo "exist";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "ok";
    }
?>
```

Comment: this is ok.can i know the way to getthe error message before he click the submit button